# Best article to use in complex-compound sentence

Tags: word-choice, complex-sentences

I'm writing documentation for a piece of software I worked on and I came across an odd sentence format that puzzled me. I was wondering if there might be a conclusive answer on the matter:

In the event that a complex compound sentence contains two independent clauses and one dependent adjective clause, but each independent clause would require different articles to tie with the dependent adjective clause, would the best article to use be the lattermost article?

**Example:** "create a" vs. "update your"

> Everyone needs an updated google account to access the document. *Please create, or update, your account before the meeting.*

---

I do not have a background in English, please excuse any incorrectly used terminology! I did some googling beforehand in order to better articulate my question so it's possible I misunderstood something in my haste.

Comment: In your example it's "create _your account_" or "update _your account_".

Comment: Not sure about general rules, but "create your account" is fine in this context - once you create an account it is your account. It seems the best option here.

Comment: @StuartF I agree that it's logically fine, but (having grown up in the US) I find it a bit odd and would suspect that the author of the phrase is not a native speaker of English.

Comment: The *specific* example is a bad one, because the same "determiner" (not "article") ***your*** works fine for both referents. Offhand I can't come up with an example where that *wouldn't* be the case, but (short of wholesale rephrasing) the "default" rules of English would normally mean you'd use the determiner / article / whatever that applied to ***the most recently mentioned referent*** (not the ***first-mentioned*** referent).

Comment: Remove the commas and you’re good to go: *Please create or update your account before the meeting.* As mentioned elsewhere, *create your account* is perfectly good.

Comment: @FF It works fine individually, but the different usages (prototypical 'your' / anticipatory 'your') don't harmonise too well IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific example, "create your account" is perfectly, 100%, correct and normal.

(For example, it's completely normal to say "Buy your new car at Fattie Motors!", or, "Buy a new car at Fattie Motors!")

Hence "Please create, or update, your account before the meeting." is perfectly correct *in this example*.

---

The general answer to your question, is that you can't. You have to use two separate articles and there's no real rule on whether that will sound natural.

- Please create an, or update your, account.

Is 100% grammatical, but a little "aggressive" or "bureaucratic" sounding.

- I want to be near, and lean against, your shoulder.

Is perfectly OK sounding and flows.

Comment: *Please create an, or update your, account* strikes me as awkward, and nothing like "100% fine".

Comment: Thank you for your response @Fattie, I accepted this answer as I felt the other answer (while a good avenue to pursue in practical cases) didn't actually address the question.

Answer (score 4):

I would rewrite to avoid the question.  A few options, two more verbose:

> Please create a new account or update your existing account before the meeting.

> Please update your existing account or create a new one before the meeting.

And one less:

> Please ensure that you have one before the meeting.

Comment: Yes, this is the less dodgy solution. Choosing (as OP suggests) 'a' certainly, and 'your' arguably, is perpetrating grammatical syllepsis.